# RT thread running slower as SCHED_OTHER threads increases

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time, scheduler

I had tested a program in order to calculate computing time in a
machine with 48  intel cpu cores.

1) when running ./test, it outputs like this:

```
MM: 324.039000 ms
MM: 324.052000 ms
MM: 324.079000 ms
MM: 324.042000 ms
MM: 324.060000 ms
MM: 324.052000 ms
MM: 324.026000 ms
MM: 324.040000 ms
MM: 324.075000 ms
MM: 324.011000 ms
MM: 324.072000 ms
```

2) running other programs, like sample code 2

```
./aa &
./aa &
....
about 30 times
```

3) ./test output changes:

```
MM: 354.601000 ms
MM: 322.289000 ms
MM: 322.250000 ms
MM: 322.348000 ms
MM: 354.700000 ms
MM: 322.556000 ms
MM: 354.834000 ms
MM: 354.816000 ms
MM: 354.777000 ms
MM: 354.812000 ms
MM: 322.451000 ms
MM: 322.507000 ms
MM: 322.473000 ms
```

4) For purpose to decrease computing cost time, I had tried:

1. set test policy to `SCHED_RR`/`SCHED_FIFO`, and priority to 50/98
   `chrt -f -p 98 5911`
2. bind test to specific cpu `taskset -pc 4 5911`
3. limit aa processes to other cpus `for i in $(ps -ef |grep aa|awk '{print $2}'); do echo $i; taskset -pc 5-47 $i; done`

It still not working, the result is not good.

```
MM: 322.316000 ms
MM: 322.307000 ms
MM: 326.739000 ms
MM: 354.399000 ms
MM: 354.662000 ms
MM: 354.740000 ms
MM: 322.275000 ms
```

5. But when limit aa processes to a small cpuset, it works, `for i in $(ps -ef |grep aa|awk '{print $2}'); do echo $i; taskset -pc 5-7 $i; done`

the result:

```
MM: 322.304000 ms
MM: 322.335000 ms
MM: 322.344000 ms
MM: 322.319000 ms
MM: 322.340000 ms
MM: 322.328000 ms
MM: 322.298000 ms
MM: 322.318000 ms
```

It's quite amazing why such low priority processes can affect realtime
process, please help me!

Sample test code1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void calc() {
    int c, d, k;
    int m = 100000, q = 1, p = 1000;
    int sum;
    for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < q; d++) {
            for (k = 0; k < p; k++) {
                 sum = c * m * d * q * p * k;
            }
        }

    }
}

int main() {
    struct timeval t1, t2;
    double elapsedTime;

    while(1) {
        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
        calc();
        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
        elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
        elapsedTime += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
        printf("MM: %lf ms\n", elapsedTime);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Sample Code 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while(1) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCHED\_FIFO process with priority of 99 gets preempted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722615/sched-fifo-process-with-priority-of-99-gets-preempted)